# The width of thead differs from tbody

Tags: css, html, html-table

I need a tbody with scroll and the thead should not have a scroll. So on doing so the width of the thead reduces to the size of the text in the thead.

Is there a way to make thead width size same as tbody

This is what I have.
https://jsfiddle.net/Viraj173/jqwgkq8k/

CSS

```
tbody.scroll{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:100px;        
 position: absolute;
}

th {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #373d49;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table >
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Value
        </th>
      </tr>                             
  </thead>
  <tbody class="scroll">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Setting Value 1
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I added static widths on the table, thead and in the CSS for tbody as you've set it to position: absolute; https://jsfiddle.net/jqwgkq8k/1/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can give the width value in `<th>` tags in the `<thead>` section.
Try this :

```
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="108px" >
          <center> Value</center>
        </th>
      </tr>                       
  </thead>
```

like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QdgJbg

or you can just edit in css like this :

```
 tbody.scroll{
      overflow-y: auto;
      height:20vh;        
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }

    th {
        color: #ffffff;
        background: #373d49;
        padding: 5px;
        width:110px;
        text-align: left;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        font-size: 14px;
        wight:20vh;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNRwWW

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 th {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #373d49;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right:100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: You should never use padding to make up for lost width. Changing the copy inside the TH will alter the width.

Comment: :) just for the case

Answer (score 0):

this is after I modified the code

```
tbody.scroll{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height:20vh;        
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ya1c55x/

Comment: On adding one more column it does not work, as the scroll is coming next to the first column.

Comment: do you mean you add the column on tbody?

Comment: what is your goal?
look at this https://jsfiddle.net/3jk8m02q/
I added second column on tbody, and the scroll is coming after second column

Comment: The goal is the thead will be defined before hand. And the values in the tbody will be be added dynamically. The table will have 5+ columns and 'X' number of rows. I want the thaed and the tbody to have same width

Comment: Checkout this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gzfhnk02/, 
you can add the column and row dynamically and the scroll will appear after last column.
Let me know if this help you.